# Is there a way to access a server from a different device in the same LAN, if device2 doesn't know device1's private IP?

Tags: networking, server

I'm serving an app that I want to be accessible from different devices in the same network. From what I've seen, I can do that by accessing the server's private IP. But the other devices have no way of knowing that. Is there a way to setup something like an internal domain?

Comment: The question really doesn't have anything to do with Go.  It's a networking question.

Comment: DNS is probably the best bet or you can manually bind a hostname to an IP in `/etc/hosts` if your on Linux. Like @Daniel Farrell said, this is not Go question and more of a networking question.

Comment: Two things i can think here, free stuff i mean, 1/ mdns, various go implementations exists 2/ using an onion, host the service over tor, totally over kill, but as long as you need not UDP, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes of this answer I'll refer to HTTP as the protocol, which is by far the widest and most frequently used.  If it's something else, the principles are the same.

The first option to consider is 'just' using the IP address.   `https://192.168.0.3/` isn't so bad to remember; IPv6 is worse, being longer.  You could email, chat, or otherwise link your users to the address so you wouldn't have to remember it.  Most home networks use DHCP by default, but usually give the same address to the same MAC address unless there's so much device turnover that the ip pool is depleted, so the addresses rarely change in practice.  Additionally, most routers leave IP space that is not part of the DHCP pool and you can statically configure that on your server to take any IP changes out of the equation.

The appeal of the IP address method is that it's low investment.  It's ready to work now.  The downside is that if your IP address *does* change, your clients now can't reach the service as currently configured.  Enter DNS.  DNS comes into the equation when the DHCP-provided DNS servers are used by clients to query for the record of names such as `stackoverflow.com`.

The DNS servers on a home network are usually ones provided by the ISP (or hopefully, because ISPs are typically bad at providing good DNS, you'd point at cloudflare (1.1.1.1) or Google (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4) or some other decent DNS provider for public DNS.  Either way, the point is, your currently configured DNS servers are probably *not* able to be configured to serve records of your devising.

That leaves you with 4 options: public DNS, private DNS server, "borrowed" DNS domains, or /etc/hosts.

Public DNS can serve a private IP address, and this is probably the next easiest solution.  You'll have to pay to register a domain and buy dns hosting (many dns registrars provide dns service for free).  You can then own a name like `myhouse.net` and add an "A" (address) record for `app.myhouse.net` with a value of your local IP address.  Any public query for the name will look up to your internal IP address, but that's not much of a disclosure (they knew you were on one of the RFC 1918 address spaces) and they could spearfish and xss you just as easily with a domain name, so for home use, I'd call publishing a private ipv4 address to public DNS can essentially be done with impunity.  Note these address spaces are non routable - they can't be accessed from the internet and conflict with many other folks' home network IP space as well.

Private DNS.  As we've discussed, you probably don't have a DNS server in your network, or you wouldn't be asking this question.  You're using public DNS servers for resolution.  So there's nowhere for you to define a domain  and records like `app.myhouse.local`.  The first step to private DNS would be to create or acquire a server which you can provide via DHCP to your local clients, and can be configured with your private domain records.  This server would be configured to also do public queries recursively, so it could be used for all DNS traffic on the network.  This way, you get to "invent" your own "private" domain that's not part of public knowledge.  This is obviously heavy touch.  You might be able to find some sort of service that would allow you to do a thing like this online, otherwise you'll need to install software like Bind or equivalent.  On the plus side, it's free, and knowing more about DNS is always a good investment.

"Borowed" DNS - by this I refer to services like https://www.noip.com/ which will allow you to create a host record under one of *their* domains.  They often also include software and an API by means of which you can update the record to point to your dynamic IP address.  I do not know whether you could store a private IP address in these services.  The domain name would be one of theirs, not one of your choosing (something like `myhouse.noip.com`)  But they're often cheap or free, and they do solve the immediate problem of creating a DNS record.  Again, the record would be a *private* address in *public* dns and could be queried from anywhere in the world.

/etc/hosts: this file (which also exists in windows, interestingly enough) provides a local system an alternative name resolution system to DNS.  It typically takes precedence over DNS (ie it's checked first) and could be used to define a record on most of your hosts.  I don't know how you'd do it on tablets or phones, and it's obviously something you'd have to set up in advance - not a great fit for your use case.

Looking at these options, I'd recommend you consider one of the borrowed dns domain providers first.  IF that seems good, you're done.  If you can't justify putting your private IP address into public DNS, that will force you to go that route.  Maybe just using the IP address will work fine.

Comment: `So there's nowhere for you to define a domain and records like app.myhouse.local` mdns/bonjour/avahi does not need a dns server. It announces itself to the network over a multicast IP.